Calculate number of Nash Equilibria with $11$ players
I'm doing some exercises from Joel Watson's Strategy, specifically Chapter $9$ exercise $13$. The question is as below:

Consider the following $n$-player game. Simultaneously and independently, the players each either select $X$, $Y$, or $Z$. The payoffs are defined as follows:

Each player who selects $X$ obtains a payoff equal to $\gamma$, where $\gamma$ is the number of players who select $Z$.
Each player who selects $Y$ obtains a payoff of $2\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is the number of players who select $X$.
Each player who selects $Z$ obtains a payoff of $3\beta$, where $\beta$ is the number of players who select $Y$.
Note that $\alpha + \beta + \gamma =n$.


Part (c) asks to find the number of Nash equilibria if $n=11$.

I got a condition for Nash equilibria ( $\gamma = 2\alpha = 3\beta$ ) which is that of the $11$ players, $6$ must choose $Z$, $3$ players must choose $X$, and $2$ must choose $Y$.


Could someone give me a hint as to how to find the number of Nash equilibria from here ( assuming I'm going down the right path )?.
